# Dudas y fallos en las métricas con InfluxDB, a partir de una ejecución de Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Estoy realizando pruebas en las que estoy ejecutando JMeter, instalado en mi máquina, y las vuelco hacia InfluxDB de dos maneras distintas.
La primera a través de Localhost, por lo que para ello me he descargado una imagen de InfluxDB a través de dockerhub, y la he corrido a través del puerto 8086. Defino las opciones de mi Backend Listener en JMeter para ejecutar la prueba:

influxdbMetricsSender: org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb.HttpMetricsSender -
influxdbUrl:  http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?org=Viewnext&bucket=prueba_localhost -
application: JMeterSets -
measurement: jmeter -
summaryOnly: true -
samplersRegex: .* -
percentiles: 90;95;99 -
testTitle: RealTimeMetrics -
eventTags: (vacío) -
influxdbToken: el que me indica el InfluxDB cuando accedo creando el usuario, la clave, organización y el bucket.

Ejecuto con 10 hilos, un periodo de 30 segundos y Loop Count:1; en HTTP Request indico la página deportiva as.com.

En InfluxDB recupero....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aunque me de un error cuando le doy al Submit para visualizar métricas ( unsupported input type for mean aggregate: string), no me preocupa tanto como lo que me sucede con el segundo caso....

Realizo la misma prueba pero para un Cluster que tengo en un entorno con Openshift Client de IBM Cloud. Los datos que empleo son los siguientes:

influxdbMetricsSender: org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb.HttpMetricsSender (igual que para Localhost) -
influxdbUrl:  http://influxdb-ltt-esteban-garzon.escuela-fra02-b3c-4x16-4282826dce7d155229a320302e775459-0000.eu-de.containers.appdomain.cloud/orgs/1eb590bb736d53e9/api/v2/write?org=Viewnext&bucket=prueba -
A partir de aquí, el resto de datos son todos iguales a los de la prueba anterior, a excepción como no, del token, que para OC es distinto.

En InfluxDB recupero....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puede comprobarse, en este segundo caso no me aparece el Filter, ni del Event, ni de la aplicación definida en Jmeter (JMeterSets), por lo que no puedo ni tan siquiera intentar extraer las métricas de mi ejecución, aunque me fallen como es el caso anterior del Localhost.

¿Porqué me pasa esto?, ¿qué tengo que configurar en InfluxDB para que desde OC pueda al menos tratar de extraer las métricas?. Modifiqué el parámetro influxdbUrl, para que incluyera el path /api/v2 antes de incluir los parámetros de entrada de la Organización y el Bucket pero no va, ni con esta ruta ni sin ella.

Por cierto, la versión de InfluxDB para ambos casos, tanto para OC como para Localhost es la misma: 2.0.8.

También me gustaría saber porqué me da el fallo en la primera prueba, "unsupported input type for mean aggregate: string", parece que le estoy introduciendo un dato erróneo pero exactamente no se cuál puede ser.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía mal el enlace en Openshift cuando lo definí en Jmeter en InfluxDbUrl, no estaba bien incluído el path, independientemente de que tenía que añadir /api/v2 y después los parámetros de entrada (organización y bucket)... Por cierto, desconocía también que para actualizar InfluxDB no se hacía a través del botón que hay a la izquierda del Time Range, sino actualizando la página sin más....
El resultado extraño que me sale en Localhost es producido básicamente por no seleccionar bien los datos de entrada en la Query.

Comment: En lugar de escribir _solucionado_, [acepta tu respuesta](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.